# Send POST request with the same name of parameters in C#

Tags: c#, rest, http-post

I want to send POST request with many parameters with the same name:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new [] {
  new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("group_id", "344"),
    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("group_id", "20"),
    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("group_id", "456")
});


HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost/api", content);
```

But if I use above request I get response only for the first group_id (with 344 ID). Do you have any idea how I can obtain *"group_id[]=344&group_id[]=20&group_id[]=456"* using *FormUrlEncodedContent* ?

Comment: Have you tried passing group_id as key and value as array like this [344, 20, 456] ?

Comment: I tried something like:


`FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("group_id", new string[] {"344", "20"} )
            });`

But, I get errors: 
1. _The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent.FormUrlEncodedContent(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>)' has some invalid arguments_

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but took me some time to figure this out, so here's the answer:

You should use brackets in your keys like this:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new [] {
  new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("group_id[]", "344"),
    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("group_id[]", "20"),
    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("group_id[]", "456")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple key-value pairs with the same keys.
That's something which is usually never allowed.
These key-value pairs will be ignored:
`new KeyValuePair<string, string>("group_id", "20"),
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("group_id", "456")`

The API which expects this kind of input must change its design.